# how to hide a window

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Like

window.open();

window.close();

Do we have any facility to hide a window.

I have a window opened on a aspx page.
That window has a button which opens second window.
When 2nd window is opened I want to hide the 1st window.
Is there a way?

Plz Suggest me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think so. "Hiding", in every desktop system I know, would in effect be minimizing or hiding it to the system tray, both of which is to my knowledge impossible in JavaScript, even using the `window.resizeTo` function.

If you're building a web application for a limited range of users, and you can control what software they use, it could be possible with [Mozilla Prism](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism), a lightweight browser that displays web applications without the usual browser interface. But that's something entirely different and probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Can you close the first window when the button is pressed (store any data you want to keep). When the user is finished with the second window, close it then re-open the first window, restoring and necessary data.

Comment: I dont want to perform any actions on 1st window after 2nd window is opened. Requirement is, when 2nd window is closed parent aspx page should be reloaded, so I am callind window.opener function on 1st window via 2nd window.